# Where is the event name located in configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, model

Where is the event name located in configuration? For example I'm looking for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event.
Where is it stored in configuration?

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
    array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId))
);
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to Magento SE! I think your question is somewhat unclear in what you mean with "configuration". As you can see from the two answers, this part was interpreted in different ways. Could you clarify in your question what you mean with configuration?

Comment: please clarify  the question..Otherwise question goes to closed